# Update totals dynamically based on checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript

it's checkout page checkbox where have option add support click on checkbox support and get the price from dataset "p" add into total and add "checked" class in input when click will happen again. Check if have checked class first remove it and remove price from total. This all works fine if i play this thing with one checkbox but it doesn't work well, when i check 2 checkboxes and try to un-check first one, it doesn't remove class or change price like before.

Here is code...

```js
const checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('.extendCheckbox');
const checkboxArray = Array.from(checkBox);

/// Add for each on that array
checkboxArray.forEach(cur => {

  cur.addEventListener('focus', () => {

    // click happend on focus one
    cur.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Get prices 
      const totalPri = parseInt(totalPrice.textContent.split('$')[1]);
      const extedP = parseInt(cur.dataset.p);
      // if already check remove and total it
      if (cur.classList.contains('checked')) {
        cur.classList.remove('checked');

        return totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPri - extedP}`;
      };
      // If already not selected

      if (!cur.classList.contains('checked')) {

        // add class on that input
        cur.classList.add('checked');
        // cur.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');

        // Add into total
        return totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPri + extedP}`
      }

      return 1;

    })

    // Focus end
  })

  // Foreach end
})
```

```html
<input class="extendCheckbox" id="support" type="checkbox" data-id="5e49329be766f54c809fcc99" data-p="11">
```

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add one listener inside another listener. Every time the first event occurs you add an additional copy of the second listener.

Comment: The return value of an event listener isn't used for anything.

Comment: If you want to know if a checkbox is checked, use `if (cur.checked)`.

Comment: @Barmar it was only way i knew to select all check boxes with querySelectorAll and yes event listener return isn't doing anything, sorry i forgot to remove i was working on some solutions...

Comment: You can add two event listeners to `cur` without putting them inside each other.

Comment: Why do you need the `focus` event on a checkbox anyway? `click` should be enough.

Comment: @Barmar  You was right i don't need focus one. It work fine without it, i was working on it for hours i haven't done anything else. I was trying different solution but i was not removing previous code. At least now i can go for eat Lol... Thank you

Comment: @MuizzAhmed : if performance and maintainability does matter for your app, I have few improvements to suggest, you may find those in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384414/11299053) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `focus` listener, all you need for a checkbox is `click`.

And use `if/else` for the two possible states of the class, rather than calling `cur.classList.contains()` twice.

```js
const checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('.extendCheckbox');
const checkboxArray = Array.from(checkBox);
let totalPrice = document.getElementById("total");

/// Add for each on that array
checkboxArray.forEach(cur => {

  // click happend on focus one
  cur.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Get prices 
    const totalPri = parseInt(totalPrice.textContent.split('$')[1]);
    const extedP = parseInt(cur.dataset.p);
    // if already check remove and total it
    if (cur.classList.contains('checked')) {
      cur.classList.remove('checked');

      totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPri - extedP}`;
    } else {
      // If already not selected
      // add class on that input
      cur.classList.add('checked');
      // cur.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');

      // Add into total
      totalPrice.textContent = `$${totalPri + extedP}`
    }

  })

  // Foreach end
})
```

```html
<input class="extendCheckbox" id="support" type="checkbox" data-id="5e49329be766f54c809fcc99" data-p="11"> $11
<input class="extendCheckbox" id="other" type="checkbox" data-p="20"> $20
<div id="total">$0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of very poor decisions you made while developing above code:

- basic query by common `className` is much faster performed with [`Element.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), though you could have taken an advantage of `Document.querySelectorAll()` for querying `:checked` checkboxes (see the demo below for details)
- Translating string to array and back to string again (in this line `parseInt(totalPrice.textContent.split('$')[1])`) is also a waste of performance, you could've better strip off `$` part (one character long), like `parseInt(totalPrice.slice(1))` but with `data-*` attributes you don't need to parse anything at all
- Set up event listener inside another event listener is a bad choice from performance standpoint as well, as you create new instance of inner listener upon each event of the outer listener
- Toggling `className` `checkbox` is not actually required - there's a `checked` property in-place already

Considering all the above, you'd be much better off with something, like:

```js
const checkboxes = [...document.getElementsByClassName('extendCheckbox')],
      totalNode = document.getElementById('total'),
      sumChecked = () => (
        checked =  [...document.querySelectorAll('.extendCheckbox:checked')]||[],
        checked.length ? checked.reduce((total,{dataset:{price}}) => total+=+price, 0) : 0
      )

totalNode.textContent = `$${sumChecked()}`

checkboxes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', () => totalNode.textContent = `$${sumChecked()}`))
```

```html
<label><input class="extendCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-id="0" data-price="30">$30</label><label><input class="extendCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-id="1" data-price="40">$40</label><label><input class="extendCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-id="2" data-price="50">$50</label><div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: @Barmar : had to leave for a while, couldn't finish editing, now I have a nice and straightforward solution to suggest, though it's a bit too late ;)